# is it possible to float divs to the sides & have them stick to the sides (not scroll with page). how?

Tags: css, html, width, css-float

**is it possible to float a #sidebar to the side of the #content & have the #content & #sidebar stick to the sides without wrapping??**

I don't mean scroll with the page, I mean when you zoom out or in, that they stick to the sides of the page. The basic principle I gather, is to give the #parent_container div a greater width in px than the #container & #sidebar divs so that it doesn't wrap the #content & #sidebar inside. & i should use a reasonable width in the #parent_container cuz some screens or resolutions are not that large or not hd. the problem with this is that i have a large gap between the body & the #parent_container.

Gratitude for the help ^_^

Comment: Show your code first plz for better understanding. You can think of using [position:fixed;.](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a tad confusing to me... Wont position fixed do what you want?

Comment: see i want to float a div to the side of another without having them wrapping with i zoom in or go to a lower resolution. the way to do this i understand is to have a parent div with a width of, for instance, 800px. Then your to divs in that div won't wrap, it'll just zoom the parent div. i've tested this & it works but there is a large gap between the parent div & the body now since i have a high resolution screen. i want to know how to float the div to the side without having the gap between it's parent div & the body.

Comment: never mind about this one anymore. i'm not going to compromise usability for profit. gratitude anywhow ^_^

Comment: They should not be able to wrap if you use position fixed as they are taken out if context. I think I will be able to help you, but I have serious problems visualizing what you want to do.